# Which is best in performance speed for an android application: storing in database or hard disk?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application, i have a genre list where, according to the selections made the thumbnails are uploaded to the selected one. I do the uploading of thumbnails by parsing my xml file. Even at the second time of selecting a genre from the list, loading time is same.

If the thumbnails are stored or cached , can the time for loading be reduced?

Which is best- storing in hard disk or creating a database?

Thanks in Advance,
Niki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the purpose: if you actually need a database - meaning that you need 1 or more tables with columns filled with various data. Or otherwise is you have a simple list with items it would be more efficient to keep them on hard disk.

Comment: is it good to do by parsing from xml file or by using database?

Comment: I would've chosen using database, as it gives you a lot more abilities, that parsing xml. For instance, you may select not all the records, but get them partially which would create an illusion that loading completed faster. At the same time you may asynchroniously load the rest.

Comment: Or you can use "mixed" solution to get advantages of the both: create [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) with _data field so when you select resultset into Cursor, you can call getInputStream() on it to retrieve InputStream of the external file.

Comment: what will happen if we change the xml version?